# Best of PSE 2016?

Tags: feature-request

I noticed that '
Programming Puzzles & Code Golf' have a best of 2016 meta competition kind of thing (see [here](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/best-of-ppcg-2016-call-for-categories?cb=1) for the post). Should we do the same? If not why not? And if so how should we go about doing?

Comment: the site cultures are a lot different but do think its worthwhile to go back and highlight standout content/ activity somehow :) but the format or process may be questioned/ challenged/ criticized :|

Comment: That would indeed be cool. Dunno if it'll work out though.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, I think we should do this.

At first I thought that "best of" would be too vague to be successful, but looking at the [example from Puzzles and Code Golf](https://codegolf.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/10938/best-of-ppcg-2016-call-for-categories?cb=1) I see that by establishing specific categories it is possible to come up with sensible best-of's.

I think we should move on to a meta post establishing the categories.