# Best of PSE 2016 - Best question

Tags: discussion

**What was, in your opinion, the best question asked in 2016?**

Vote either by posting an answer linking to your favorite question, with a *brief* description of why it's your favorite, or by upvoting an existing post.
Voting lasts two weeks, i.e. until Jan 29 2017.

This is part of the [Best-of PSE 2016](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-and-categories).
If you are interested in providing a prize bounty for the winner (mostly highly upvoted answer of this meta post), please comment.

Comment: Here's a tool that may help people looking for good answers: http://data.stackexchange.com/physics/query/615916/2016-questions

Comment: @heather but we want good questions for this award not good answers

Comment: @Kenshin, it produces questions, not answers.

Comment: @heather ok cool, you just said in your initial comment it was for answers so wanted to clarify :)

Answer (score 3):

## [Partition function for Gaussian white noise](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/285886/partition-function-for-gaussian-white-noise)

I like this question because it brings together two seemingly disparate areas of physics: noise (i.e. stochastic processes) and the partition function.
The latter of these two is normally encountered in the context of statistical mechanics, so it's interesting and aesthetically pleasing to see a link established between teh partition function and stochastic processes.

It's a *good question* because OP states the problem concisely, shows effort, and asks for help on a particular step.

Comment: +1 many pretty equations

Answer (score 0):

## [From discrete to continuous - why quantum *fields*?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/287399/from-discrete-to-continuous-why-quantum-fields)

This fundamental question invites us to revisit assumptions we probably originally take for granted.