# Best of PSE 2016 - Q&A rookie of the year

Tags: discussion

**Which user, who made their account in 2016, has added exceptional quality to the site *in the form of questions and answers*?**

Vote either by posting an answer linking to to a new user's profile and giving a *brief* description of why that user should win, or by upvoting an existing post.
Voting lasts two weeks, i.e. until Jan 29 2017.

This is part of the [Best-of PSE 2016](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-and-categories).
If you are interested in providing a prize bounty for the winner (mostly highly upvoted answer of this meta post), please comment.

Answer (score 13):

[heather](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/121464/heather): For exceptional research effort in her answers and making the site more open to new users from all levels.

And ~4500 reputation in the first 7 months says a lot, too...

Comment: I'd just like to say thanks - I have found this community absolutely amazing. It has helped me time and time again, and has an incredibly welcoming group of people. So thank you all =)

Answer (score 9):

[Bob Bee](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/108333/bob-bee) whose works on general relativity, black holes and gravitational waves are very enjoyable to read whilst bored at work (or other times).

~5K rep in 11 months and active in the reviews, the makings of a great contributor.

Answer (score 4):

[Farcher](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/104696/farcher)

This user has amassaed an amazing 19,265 reputation in just 11 months by adding numerous high quality questions and answers.

Answer (score 3):

[sammy gerbil](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/114696/sammy-gerbil)

Great contributor having amassed nearly 10,000 reputation in just 9 months.