# Best of PSE 2016 - Less is more

Tags: discussion

**What was the most impressively clear and concise answer in 2016?**

Note that a clear and concise to a very simple question is not necessarily particularly impressive.

Vote either by posting an answer linking to a clear and concise answer and giving a *brief* description of why that answer should win, or by upvoting an existing post.
Voting lasts two weeks, i.e. until Jan 29 2017.

This is part of the [Best-of PSE 2016](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-and-categories).
If you are interested in providing a prize bounty for the winner (mostly highly upvoted answer of this meta post), please comment.

Answer (score 3):

I would like to nominate the answer below:

[Does the Many Worlds interpretation of quantum mechanics necessarily imply every world exist?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/288614/does-the-many-worlds-interpretation-of-quantum-mechanics-necessarily-imply-every/288618#288618)

The question provides a short but very informative answer highlighting that unlike in other areas of life, on Physics.SE size isn't everything.

Comment: Thanks, but I decline the nomination. I dashed off that answer in 30 seconds and I'm not really proud of the attention it got or the ensuing discussion.

Comment: @knzhou Stephen Hawking came up with Hawking radiation under the shower (at least supposedly). And this is the "Less is more" category, so no false modesty here ;)