# Best of PSE 2016 - Most underrated answer

Tags: discussion

**What was the most underrated answer in 2016?**

Underrated could mean that an answer recieved little attention/upvotes despite being of excellent quality.

Vote either by posting an answer linking to an underrated answer and giving a *brief* description of why that answer should win, or by upvoting an existing post.
Voting lasts two weeks, i.e. until Jan 29 2017.

This is part of the [Best-of PSE 2016](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-and-categories).
If you are interested in providing a prize bounty for the winner (mostly highly upvoted answer of this meta post), please comment.

Answer (score 5):

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277183/how-can-i-adapt-classical-continuum-mechanics-equations-in-order-to-agree-with-g/284988#284988) by [pglpm](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/132418/pglpm) to the question [How can I adapt classical continuum mechanics equations in order to agree with general relativity?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/277183/how-can-i-adapt-classical-continuum-mechanics-equations-in-order-to-agree-with-g) shows a very profound conceptual understanding of classical continuum mechanics and furthermore contains a vast amount of literature and research a very interesting/relevant open topic. To me, it is strange that it only got a few upvotes.

Comment: This might also fit at http://meta.physics.stackexchange.com/q/9490/50583

Comment: Actually this answer has 10 upvotes

Comment: @Kenshin now ...

Comment: @Sanya yeah lol

Answer (score 2):

[This answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/a/296869/25301) by [tpg2114](https://physics.stackexchange.com/users/6634/tpg2114) to the question [How to initialize / bootstrap the Boris algorithm?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/q/296863/25301)

The Boris algorithm is an integrator for solving Newton's laws numerically (well really any force law). For all the questions we have on solving this type of system, no one seems to have discussed how to *start* such a system (as the positions and velocities are solved at half-steps and typically we know $x(t=0),\,v(t=0)$ and not $x(t=0),\,v(t=\Delta t/2)$).

tpg2114 gave a good answer to an interesting problem, but it's a [computational-physics](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/computational-physics) question so it got little love from the community.

Answer (score -1):

I think this answer to [What will happen if the photon has non-zero mass?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/191451/what-will-happen-if-the-photon-has-non-zero-mass/285624#285624)
 is the most underrated answer of 2016.

The post is very informative and clearly a lot of effort went into its creation.  Unfortunately at the time of posting this, it has only obtained 1 up-vote.

Comment: -1. Although very detailed, it is far too long, out of all proportion to the length of the question. More like an essay.