# Best of PSE 2016 - Best community work

Tags: discussion

**What was, in your opinion, the best answer in 2016 which where two or more authors contributed a significant fraction of the content?**

Vote either by posting an answer linking to your favorite community work, with a *brief* description of why it's your favorite, or by upvoting an existing post.
Voting lasts two weeks, i.e. until Jan 29 2017.

This is part of the [Best-of PSE 2016](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-and-categories).
If you are interested in providing a prize bounty for the winner (mostly highly upvoted answer of this meta post), please comment.