# Best of PSE 2016 - Best answer directed at the layman

Tags: discussion

**What was, in your opinion, the best layman answer in 2016?**

A layman answer is an answer directed at those without expert training in physics.

Vote either by posting an answer linking to your favorite layman answer, with a *brief* description of why it's your favorite, or by upvoting an existing post.
Voting lasts two weeks, i.e. until Jan 29 2017.

This is part of the [Best-of PSE 2016](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-and-categories).
If you are interested in providing a prize bounty for the winner (mostly highly upvoted answer of this meta post), please comment.

Answer (score -5):

I'll nominate my own answer for this one:

[What is the evidence for the existence of gravity](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/294763/what-is-the-evidence-for-the-existence-of-gravity/294771#294771)

A very clear and concise answer targeted at the layman.

Comment: Possibly there  should be a category for the best answer to the silliest/most obvious question. This is not intended to diss any genuine post from a non-trolling  OP,  but more about:  **what** are  some schools teaching, I wonder?