# Best of PSE 2016 - Best answer by a rookie

Tags: discussion

**What was the best answer posted in 2016 by a user whose account was made in 2016?**

Vote either by posting a link to your favorite answer given by a rookie, with a *brief* description of why it's your favorite, or by upvoting an existing post.
Voting lasts two weeks, i.e. until Jan 29 2017.

This is part of the [Best-of PSE 2016](https://physics.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/9423/best-of-pse-2016-description-and-categories).
If you are interested in providing a prize bounty for the winner (mostly highly upvoted answer of this meta post), please comment.

Answer (score 2):

I'd say the answer below is the best answer by a rookie in 2016.  A very informative answer by a user who created their account in 2016:

[How does Zumberge's 1981 gravitational measurements relate to gravitational waves?](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/251001/how-does-zumberges-1981-gravitational-measurements-relate-to-gravitational-wave/251014#251014)